# set metadata for the payment intent that was created by subscription stripe

Tags: nestjs, stripe-payments, subscription

Im adding a subscription feachure in my program. Im using stripe.
When my webhook getting payment intent with status "succeeded" im taking metadata from that payment intent. Metadata contains productId form my database, userId (user that bought the product) and passing it to my function that updates the database and giving the customer his product.

So the problem is I can only pass the metadata to the subscription object and not the payment intent that creates automaticly every billing cycle. The possible solution is to update the payment metadata like this:

```
...

        const subscription = await this.stripe.subscriptions.create({
            customer: customer.id,
            items: [{ price: "price_........." }],
            expand: ["latest_invoice.payment_intent"],
            metadata: {
                productId: productId,
                userId: user.id,
            },
        });

        
        await this.stripe.paymentIntents.update(subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent.id, {
            metadata: {
                subscriptionId: subscription.id,
                userId: user.id,
                productId: product.id,
            }
        });
```

but this will not set the metadata for the next payment intent in the billing cycle

May be you have the same problem and you have some other solution. Please let me know how you worked it out.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple ways you can solve for this. If metadata only contains static info like product id and user id, then you could store a mapping of subscription id -> product id, user id, etc. in your database. And instead of listening to payment_intent.succeeded events, you could listen to invoice.payment_succeeded events. Then, you can inspect [the subscription id on the invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-subscription) and lookup all the data associated with that subscription id in your database. If the user id and product id you're referring to are the Stripe customer id and Stripe product id, then you also could just get that data directly from the invoice object ([customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-customer) and [product](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/object#invoice_object-lines-data)).

If it's a hard requirement that you listen to payment_intent.succeeded events instead, then you can inspect the [payment intent's invoice](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/object#payment_intent_object-invoice) in the webhook event payload and [retrieve it](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/retrieve). From there you can proceed with the steps I outlined in the above paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it's also a very strange Stripe API design when you get PaymentIntent at the end of subscription process, but can't get any Product details from it.

I retrieved Invoice from the PaymentIntent, it contains price and product fields inside `lines` property. Without using metadata.

```
intent  = Stripe::PaymentIntent.retrieve 'payment-intent-id'
invoice = Stripe::Invoice.retrieve intent.invoice
product = Stripe::Product.retrieve invoice.lines.data[0].price.product
```

But the most correct solution I guess is to save all these details in your database when you create the subscription.